# Is it possible to remove vector elements by enumeration in Java?

Tags: java

I am aware about Vector API of remove method as well as concept of Iterator.
But my question is can we use enumeration for this?Is there any minute possibility for this?

Comment: Are you asking whether there's a possibility of using `Enumeration` to remove elements from a `Vector` instead of `Iterator.remove()` or `Vector.remove()`?

Comment: yes I am asking the same

Answer (score 0):

[Enumeration](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) is a Java 1.0 class, and as many classes from that time it's less than optimal. The javadoc lists the flaws as follows

> The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the Iterator
>   interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove operation,
>   and has shorter method names.

If you don't have access to the underlying collection, there's no possibility of removing an element with just an `Enumeration`.